# Vim 8.2 Plugin help. PlugStatus not loading some of my plugins

Tags: vimrc

[image]

I need help with vim. Just starting vim but struggling with settings.
I placed the below plugin in vimrc as this:

```
Plug '~/my-prototype-plugin'
```

Also, why are some of my plugins not loaded?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You're going to have to provide a lot more information to get a good answer to your question. Based on the screenshot, it appears you have a plugin manager set up. Can you [edit] to describe which one and include the relevant parts of your vimrc? That should help us figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

A vim-plug plugin spec that includes a local file system path is an "un-managed" plugin.

```
" Unmanaged plugin (manually installed and updated)
Plug '~/my-prototype-plugin'
```

That means you intend to take care of downloading and building it. You're just telling vim-plug where you've put it.

If you want vim-plug to take care of everything it needs to just be `Plug '<github owner>/<github project>'` like

```
Plug 'vim-airline/vim-airline'
```

As for the others you haven't provided enough information to definitively identify the problem. One clue is some of the vim-plug code:

```
" `s:loaded` entry can be missing if PlugUpgraded  
if is_dir && get(s:loaded, name, -1) == 0 
    ...
    let msg .= ' (not loaded)'
```

That suggests something like running the `PlugUpgrade` command but not following that with a vim restart or, possibly, a run of `PlugUpdate`.

It may also occur if you've configured lazy loading for a plugin. Something with the `'on'` or `'for'` clause like...

```
Plug 'guns/vim-sexp', {'for': 'clojure'}
```

With this configuration I could get the "not loaded" message if I checked status without having loaded a Clojure file.

I'd urge you to read everything from the project's github page. Much useful information including the answer to the first question is there.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you simply copied the [example snippet from vim-plug's readme https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug/blob/master/README.md#example verbatim, while setting up vim-plug.

That example is not really meant to be used directly, but more to illustrate vim-plug's capabilities.

For the unmanaged plug-in:

> ```
> " Unmanaged plugin (manually installed and updated)
> Plug '~/my-prototype-plugin'
> ```

That's meant to be for a plug-in you're writing yourself, as the name "prototype plugin" suggests.

If you create a new directory `~/my-prototype-plugin` (note that `~` means your home directory here) and add that snippet to your vimrc, vim-plug will be happy to load your plug-in but it won't try to install or upgrade it (since it's not on a GitHub repository to start with.)

You're probably getting this error because you added this line but you don't have any `~/my-prototype-plugin` directory with a plug-in you're writing. So you should **just remove that line from your vimrc.**

Regarding the `(not loaded)` ones, these two come from that same example in the readme file:

> ```
> " On-demand loading
> Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree', { 'on':  'NERDTreeToggle' }
> Plug 'tpope/vim-fireplace', { 'for': 'clojure' }
> ```

They're using the `'on'` and `'for'` clauses of vim-plug, which means they're only loaded when a specific command is executed, or when a file of a specific type is opened. So that's also expected. **That's normal, expected behavior. Nothing to fix here.**

(Not sure why you're also getting it with `goyo.vim`, that doesn't seem to be coming from that sample readme file and the installation instructions on `goyo.vim` don't mention any conditional clauses.)

So I guess you should at least remove the `Plug` line for the inexistent plug-in in your home directory, that one doesn't make sense to you.

Regarding the other lines you got from the example, I guess it's OK if you want to keep them... But you don't really have to. As I mentioned, that list is mostly an example of how to use vim-plug features, such as the conditional loads.

You could just remove all of those `Plug` lines and everything would keep working. Just add `Plug` lines for the plug-ins you actually*want* to use in Vim and vim-plug will manage those for you.

Comment: Thank you for your time.